# snapshot of softlayer block device(Endurance volume)

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I created snapshot by using below api of Block Storage (Endurance) on SoftLayer.

```
res = client['Network_Storage_Iscsi'].createSnapshot('', id=12686459)
```

I got result in which it is showing volume id as `'volumeId': 13348463`.

When I try to get list of snapshots for my volume I get empty list:

```
res = client['Network_Storage_Iscsi'].getSnapshotsForVolume(id=12686459)
```

Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nop you did not miss anything, the command is the correct and it works, likely you got an empty list because the snapshot was in "creating proccess" once it is completed you should get the snapshot. So try again.

Regards

Comment: yes you are right...snapshot appeared now, snapshot creation took long time...thanks

Comment: great I would thank you a lot if can mark the answer as the correct and vote :)

Comment: I have noticed this takes longer than using the web portal. How come?

Comment: The portal uses the API for perform its actions, I do not think that they can have differents times to execute the actions